Is it true that $\widehat{(\delta_{x_{0}}\otimes T)} = \hat{\delta}_{x_{0}}\otimes \hat{T}$?
For a fixed $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the Dirac delta distribution $\delta_{x_{0}}$. Its Fourier transform is given by $\hat{\delta}_{x_{0}}(p) = e^{-px_{0}}$, in the sense that $\hat{\delta}_{x_{0}}(p)$ is the distribution defined by the action:
$$\langle \hat{\delta}_{x_{0}},\phi\rangle = \int dp e^{-ipx_{0}}\phi(p) = \hat{\phi}(x_{0})$$
for every test function $\phi$.
Suppose we are given a tempered distribution $T \in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, whose Fourier transform is $\hat{T}$, also a distribution. As far as I know, tensor products of distributions are well-defined, so I can consider the tensor product $\hat{\delta}_{x_{0}}\otimes \hat{T}$. Is it true that $\widehat{(\delta_{x_{0}}\otimes T)} = \hat{\delta}_{x_{0}}\otimes \hat{T}$? In other words, does it follow that:
$$\langle \widehat{(\delta_{x_{0}}\otimes T)},\phi\rangle = \langle \hat{\delta}_{x_{0}}\otimes\hat{T},\phi\rangle = \langle \hat{T}, \langle \hat{\delta}_{x_{0}},\phi\rangle\rangle = \langle \hat{T},\hat{\phi}\rangle $$
for all test functions $\phi$?

This will actually be true even if you replace $\delta_0$ by any distribution $S$ whose Fourier transform is a measurable function with at most polynomial growth, at the very least. It's also probably not limited to that case, but it's just to make Fubini's theorem work below without much effort:
Let's say that $S$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^{d_1}$ and $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d_2}$, so that $S \otimes T$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^{d_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_2}$.
The crux of the matter is showing that, for $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_2})$:
$$\tag{$*$}\forall \zeta \in \mathbb{R}^{d_2},\quad \mathcal{F}_y\left\langle \hat{S}_\xi, \phi(\xi, y)\right\rangle(\zeta) = \left\langle \hat{S}_\xi, \mathcal{F}_y\phi(\xi, \zeta) \right\rangle$$
Once the equality $(*)$ is true, you'll be able to proceed as follows:
$$\begin{split}\left\langle \hat{S}\otimes \hat{T}, \phi\right\rangle &= \left\langle T_\zeta, \mathcal{F}_y\left\langle \hat{S}_\xi, \phi(\xi, y)\right\rangle(\zeta) \right\rangle\\
&\overset{(*)}{=} \left\langle T_\zeta, \left\langle \hat{S}_\xi, \mathcal{F}_y\phi(\xi, \zeta) \right\rangle\right\rangle\\
&= \left\langle T_\zeta, \left\langle S_\xi, \hat{\phi}(\xi, \zeta) \right\rangle\right\rangle\\
&= \left\langle \widehat{S \otimes T}, \phi\right\rangle\end{split}$$
So let's show $(*)$:
$$\begin{split}\mathcal{F}_y\left\langle \hat{S}_\xi, \phi(\xi, y)\right\rangle(\zeta) &= \mathcal{F}_y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}} \hat{S}(\xi)\phi(\xi, y) \,\mathrm{d}\xi\right)(\zeta)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}} e^{-iy\cdot\zeta}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}} \hat{S}(\xi)\phi(\xi, y) \,\mathrm{d}\xi\right) \,\mathrm{d}y\\
&\!\!\!\!\overset{\text{Fubini}}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}} \hat{S}(\xi)  \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}}e^{-iy\cdot\zeta} \phi(\xi, y) \,\mathrm{d}y\right) \,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}} \hat{S}(\xi)\mathcal{F}_y\phi(\xi, \zeta) \,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&= \left\langle \hat{S}_\xi, \mathcal{F}_y\phi(\xi, \zeta) \right\rangle\end{split}$$
and we are done.
